# How To migrate users from a Mysql database to AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to migrate users from a Wordpress database into an AWS Cognito user pool without changing the passwords. Is this possible ?

The passwords in the Mysql database are MD5 hash.
Did anyone manage to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Migrating Users directly not possible. i m working on similar functionality, for this i used `aws-sdk-php` for making cognito signUp and other requests

you can use `user_register` hook for signing Up same user on cognito as user resister on wordrpess. you can get both email and pass from `$userdata` in un-encrypted form to send it to cognito.

another thing if user need to reset or forget password for this you will have to make `adminSetUserPassword` request by using password reset hooks.